# How does rails tag a photo and get mouse action with x,y?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, image

In my APP, I use `paperclip` to manage my upload pictures. When I show my image on browser, I want to tag some points on this picture, when I clicked, It's show a box to let me enter some informations, after save, `logged the x,y on this picture at the same time`, record in database.

When I refresh this page, I can see the points on this picture(load the db points records.) How can I accomplish this case? I try `jquery_picture_tag-rails`, but when I follow the first step(I use rails 4.2.2) :

> Add this line in app/assets/javascripts/application.js: //= require
>   jquery-picture-tag

shows:

```
couldn't find file 'jquery-picture-tag' with type 'application/javascript'
```

does someone can give some tips? or does it can easy accomplish only with jQuery?
Thanks.